# form.is_valid() always returns false

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have tried all the solutions given on SO but was not able to slve this

**view.py**

```
def signup(request):   
    form = SignupForm(request.GET)
    print("%s"%request.GET['hobby'])
    form.errors
    #h=SignupForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        email = request.GET['email']
        location = request.GET['location']  users=User(username=username,email=email,password=request.GET['password'],location=location)
        user_profile = request.user.profile
        user_profile.location = location
        user_profile.save()        
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('mtweet/')
    return render(request,'mtweet/signup.html',{'SignupForm':form})
```

**form.py**

```
class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    username=forms.CharField(label = " Username",required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(label = "Email",required=True)
    password = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput,required=True)
    location=forms.CharField(label="Location",required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email","location")
```

**signup.html**

```
<div id="register">
 <form method="post" action="{% url 'mtweet.views.signup' %}">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <table>
        {{ SignupForm.as_p}}
   </table>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add your view (the template).

Comment: **signup.html**

<div id="register">
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'mtweet.views.signup' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
 <table>
        {{ SignupForm.as_p}}
 </table>        
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>

Comment: sorry.....new to SO, not able to edit properly

Comment: What error do you see when its not valid?

Comment: Your form is being submitted as `POST`, I see you commented out this line in your source: `#h=SignupForm(request.POST)`; if you replace this with `form = SignupForm(request.POST, request.FILES)` do you still get the same error?

Comment: in view.py......the form.is_valid() always returns false .....

Comment: @burhan ya still same thing

Comment: Why do you have `request.user.profile`? Are you trying to create a user, or sign up an existing user?

Comment: i am creating a user.....

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code; let me try and re-write it:

```
class SignupForm(forms.Form):
    username=forms.CharField(label = " Username",required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(label = "Email",required=True)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,required=True)
    location=forms.CharField(label="Location",required=False)

def signup(request):   
    form = SignupForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        location = form.cleaned_data['location']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
        user.save()
        user_profile = user.profile
        user_profile.location = location
        user_profile.save()        
        return HttpResponseRedirect('mtweet/')
    else:
        return render(request,'mtweet/signup.html',{'SignupForm':form})
    return render(request,'mtweet/signup.html',{'SignupForm':SignupForm()})
```

Comment: but i still have the same problem......is_valid() is always returning false......